# Image overlay with small memory footprint

Tags: java, image, memory

Is there a way with Java to overlay text onto an image, for example in a corner, without loading the entire image into memory? Ideally only the region where the text will go will be loaded. The other regions will remain unchanged. This would be in regard to dealing with large images, or even to just managing memory usage better.

Comment: Stored in a file on the disk.